# SQUID Cache version 3.5.10 for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu

Tags: squid

I have searched far and wide but now I need to ask for help.

I have a few squid servers that need an IP address change. Since the address change I get the following in the log files when I start squid:

```
2015/12/08 12:16:43 kid1| Starting Squid Cache version 3.5.10 for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu...
2015/12/08 12:16:43 kid1| Service Name: squid
2015/12/08 12:16:43 kid1| Process ID 1743
2015/12/08 12:16:43 kid1| Process Roles: worker
2015/12/08 12:16:43 kid1| With 131072 file descriptors available
2015/12/08 12:16:43 kid1| Initializing IP Cache...
2015/12/08 12:16:43 kid1| DNS Socket created at [::], FD 6
2015/12/08 12:16:43 kid1| DNS Socket created at 0.0.0.0, FD 7
2015/12/08 12:16:43 kid1| Adding nameserver 8.8.8.8 from /etc/resolv.conf
2015/12/08 12:16:43 kid1| Adding nameserver 8.8.4.4 from /etc/resolv.conf
2015/12/08 12:16:43 kid1| helperOpenServers: Starting 5/32 'ssl_crtd' processes
2015/12/08 12:16:43 kid1| ipcCreate: fork: (12) Cannot allocate memory
2015/12/08 12:16:43 kid1| WARNING: Cannot run '/usr/lib64/squid/ssl_crtd' process.
2015/12/08 12:16:43 kid1| ipcCreate: fork: (12) Cannot allocate memory
2015/12/08 12:16:43 kid1| WARNING: Cannot run '/usr/lib64/squid/ssl_crtd' process.
2015/12/08 12:16:43 kid1| ipcCreate: fork: (12) Cannot allocate memory
2015/12/08 12:16:43 kid1| WARNING: Cannot run '/usr/lib64/squid/ssl_crtd' process.
2015/12/08 12:16:43 kid1| ipcCreate: fork: (12) Cannot allocate memory
2015/12/08 12:16:43 kid1| WARNING: Cannot run '/usr/lib64/squid/ssl_crtd' process.
2015/12/08 12:16:43 kid1| Logfile: opening log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log
2015/12/08 12:16:43 kid1| Logfile Daemon: opening log /var/log/squid/access.log
2015/12/08 12:16:43 kid1| ipcCreate: fork: (12) Cannot allocate memory
FATAL: Couldn't start logfile helper
Squid Cache (Version 3.5.10): Terminated abnormally.
CPU Usage: 0.226 seconds = 0.203 user + 0.023 sys
Maximum Resident Size: 140208 KB
Page faults with physical i/o: 0
```

My squid config looks like this:

```
acl localnet src 31.210.109.136/32
acl localnet src 213.128.87.253/32
acl localnet src 176.53.118.101/32
acl localnet src 178.211.45.99/32
acl localnet src 213.128.81.163/32
acl localnet src 176.53.22.194/32
acl localnet src 185.128.113.239
acl localnet src 185.128.113.240
acl localnet src 185.128.113.241
acl localnet src 185.128.113.242
acl localnet src 185.128.113.243
acl localnet src 185.128.113.244
acl localnet src 185.128.113.245
acl localnet src 185.128.113.246
acl localnet src 185.128.113.247
acl localnet src 127.0.0.0/8


acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl Safe_ports port 8443
acl Safe_ports port 28443
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
#http_access deny to_localhost

http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all

http_port 185.128.113.239:10001 name=10001 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB cert=/etc/ssl/certs/squid.pem
http_port 185.128.113.239:10002 name=10002 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB cert=/etc/ssl/certs/squid.pem
http_port 185.128.113.239:10003 name=10003 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB cert=/etc/ssl/certs/squid.pem
http_port 185.128.113.239:10004 name=10004 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB cert=/etc/ssl/certs/squid.pem
http_port 185.128.113.239:10005 name=10005 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB cert=/etc/ssl/certs/squid.pem
http_port 185.128.113.239:10006 name=10006 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB cert=/etc/ssl/certs/squid.pem

acl port10001 myportname 10001 src 37.35.90.3/32
http_access allow port10001
tcp_outgoing_address 185.128.113.239 port10001

acl port10001 myportname 10001 src 37.35.90.131/32
http_access allow port10001
tcp_outgoing_address 185.128.113.239 port10001

acl port10001 myportname 10001 src 82.16.22.100/32
http_access allow port10001
tcp_outgoing_address 185.128.113.239 port10001

always_direct allow all
ssl_bump allow all
sslproxy_cert_error allow all
sslproxy_flags DONT_VERIFY_PEER

cache_dir ufs /var/cache/squid 100 16 256

coredump_dir /var/cache/squid

refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320

via off
forwarded_for off

request_header_access Allow allow all
request_header_access Authorization allow all
request_header_access WWW-Authenticate allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authorization allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authenticate allow all
request_header_access Cache-Control allow all
request_header_access Content-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Content-Length allow all
request_header_access Content-Type allow all
request_header_access Date allow all
request_header_access Expires allow all
request_header_access Host allow all
request_header_access If-Modified-Since allow all
request_header_access Last-Modified allow all
request_header_access Location allow all
request_header_access Pragma allow all
request_header_access Accept allow all
request_header_access Accept-Charset allow all
request_header_access Accept-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Accept-Language allow all
request_header_access Content-Language allow all
request_header_access Mime-Version allow all
request_header_access Retry-After allow all
request_header_access Title allow all
request_header_access Connection allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Connection allow all
request_header_access User-Agent allow all
request_header_access Cookie allow all
request_header_access All deny all

connect_timeout 10 seconds
```

I have tried all sorts of things to gewt this working, but to no avail.
Here is some things I tried:

```
rm -fr /var/cache/squid
mkdir -p /var/cache/squid
chown -R squid:squid /var/cache/squid
squid -z
chown -R squid:squid /var/cache/squid
rm -fr /var/lib/ssl_db
/usr/lib64/squid/ssl_crtd -c -s /var/lib/ssl_db
chown -R squid:squid /var/lib/ssl_db/
```

Also `/usr/lib64/squid/ssl_crtd -s /var/lib/ssl_db -M 4MB -d`

But no success. Can anybody please help?

Comment: Do you have enough free memory?

Comment: Can you include the output of `uname -a` and `cat /proc/swaps`?

Comment: Here it is:
Linux vpsnpgevp01.tr.com 2.6.32-042stab112.15 #1 SMP Tue Oct 20 17:22:56 MSK 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

and

cat /proc/swaps
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/null                               partition       1048576 0       -1

Comment: This is the memory i have:
free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       1048576      28996    1019580       5124          0      20720
-/+ buffers/cache:       8276    1040300
Swap:      1048576          0    1048576


It ran fine until i had to change ip addresses.

Comment: Ok, I totally do not understand this, but I decided to do a microsoft and reboot the server and now it seems fine and it is up and running. Thank you anyway for taking a small peek.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, It seems that the server needed a reboot even though I reboot it after i changed IP addresses earlier today.

Thank you for taking a look at the problem.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know it's been fixed. Once the timeout has expired, feel free to mark this as accepted.